# ¿Qué información aparece en la sección "Destacado en Meta"?

Tags: soporte, boletín-de-comunidad

En el sitio principal, en la sección del lado derecho aparece una sección llamada *Destacado en Meta*. Ya estaba familiarizado al respecto pero hoy vi que en esa sección apareció una publicación de [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com):

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Es correcto que en esa sección aparezcan entradas de Meta Stack Exchange o se trata de algún bug? Además, ¿qué otro tipo de entradas (en cuanto a comunidades o sitios de la red) es correcto que se muestren?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que aparece en Destacado en Meta es:

- Si hay una [**elección**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election), un enlace a la que haya en curso.
- Si hay **eventos** actuales o próximos, un enlace a cada uno de ellos, encabezados por los más próximos a empezar o terminar.
- Si hay menos de 4 eventos, **publicaciones del blog** del [Stack Exchange blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/). Solo aparecerá un máximo de dos, de entre los publicados en los últimos *n* días (*n* = 10 para SOx).
- Si hay menos de 4 elementos, las preguntas de Meta que tengan la etiqueta [destacado](/questions/tagged/destacado).
- Si hay menos de 4 elementos, el resto del espacio se llena con las preguntas populares. Esto es, las etiquetadas con [discusión](/questions/tagged/discusi%c3%b3n) que no tengan ninguna etiqueta de estado (las de color rosa que solo pueden usar los moderadores, como [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)), cuya puntuación sea de al menos 3 y que se hayan publicado en las últimas dos semanas. Las que cumplen estas condiciones se eligen semi aleatoriamente.

Si hay alguna pregunta destacada o popular, al menos 1 de ellas aparecerá en la lista, incluso si hace que la longitud final de la lista supere los 4 elementos.

Además, hasta 2 de las preguntas recientes (esto es, creadas en las dos últimas semanas) con la etiqueta [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) de [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfeatured%5D%20is%3Aquestion%20created%3A14d..) aparecen en el boletín de la comunidad de *todos* los sitios.

Versión original de todo esto y algún detalle adicional en [What criteria is used to select the links that appear in the “Hot Meta Posts” block?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/209901).

Comment: Corolario: lo que sale es correcto, no un bug.

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta corta

Sí es correcto

## Respuesta Extendida

En el hilo referido por [fedorqui en el comentario a la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3434/en-la-secci%C3%B3n-destacado-en-meta-qu%C3%A9-informaci%C3%B3n-deber%C3%ADa-aparecer#comment12288_3434), se menciona el tipo de enlaces a incluir en el recuadro amarillo. Específicamente los que corresponden a Destacado en Meta son:

- las preguntas en Meta SOes con la etiqueta [destacado](/questions/tagged/destacado)
- las preguntas en Meta SOes con la etiqueta [discusión](/questions/tagged/discusi%c3%b3n) que sean recientes y con cierta cantidad de puntos.
- las destacadas en [SE Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com)

Otras cosas que podrían aparecer con su propio encabezado

- Elecciones
- Eventos
- Publicaciones de blog