# La sección "Publicaciones populares en Meta" muestra respuestas con la etiqueta [estado-completado], cuando no debería ser así

Tags: bug, estado-completado, meta, boletín-de-comunidad

Hace días que Meta está muy tranquila, de ahí que la sección *Publicaciones populares en Meta* esté prácticamente monopolizada por la propuesta [Hagamos [list] sinónimo de [lista]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3490/83), que ya implementó lois6b y, por tanto, lleva la etiqueta [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado).

Ya hace años sugerí en Meta.SE [What about capping the time a post remains in "Hot meta posts" instead of showing it for so long?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279360/209901), es decir, que una pregunta no salga eternamente en esta sección.

Pero es que, además, en este caso la pregunta no debería aparecer allí. En efecto, de acuerdo con [¿Qué información aparece en la sección "Destacado en Meta"?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3434/83), en la que traduje lo dicho en [What criteria are used to select the links that appear in the community bulletin sidebar block?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130621/209901):

> - Si hay menos de 4 elementos, el resto del espacio se llena con las preguntas populares. Esto es, las etiquetadas con [discusión](/questions/tagged/discusi%c3%b3n) que no tengan [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado), cuya puntuación sea de al menos 3 y que se hayan publicado en las últimas dos semanas. Las que cumplen estas condiciones se eligen semi aleatoriamente.

Esto viene de la explicación original que habla de capar las preguntas con [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). Por algún motivo, parece que el sistema no reconoce el sinónimo [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado) y en la sección *Publicaciones populares en Meta* muestra las preguntas que la llevan.

Parece un caso parecido a [Etiquetas de las cuestiones migradas a Meta: usar "discusión" en lugar de "discussion"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1391/83), donde el sistema parece que tampoco tenga en cuenta el sinónimo [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) → [discusión](/questions/tagged/discusi%c3%b3n).

---

Esto sigue pasando. Ahora mismo vemos la pregunta [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre etiquetas [react] y [reactjs]? ¿No deberían ser sinónimas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3951/83) en *Publicaciones populares en Meta*:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando hace un día largo que tiene la etiqueta [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado):

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

A pesar de que el CM Juan M ha indicado dos veces que está corregido, sigue sin estarlo. Hoy mismo vemos:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, que la pregunta [¿Podríamos hacer la etiqueta [management-studio] un sinónimo de ssms?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4538/83) aparece en el bloque, a pesar de que tiene la etiqueta [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado):

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Actualización 22/04/2021.
Este problema sigue si estar solucionado. Hoy vemos en publicaciones populares lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde aparece [esta pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5057/quemar-etiqueta-multiple?cb=1) que como vemos aparece con [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Interesantes enlaces. ¿Qué podemos hacer al respecto?

Comment: @lois6b esperar que el CM lo escale o, siendo más realistas, publicarlo directamente en Meta.SE para ver si un desarrollador lo puede investigar.

Comment: Le he mandado una notificacion a JuanM para que cuando tenga tiempo pueda ver qué hacer

Comment: @lois6b ¡gracias! Hace un par de meses pasamos un listado de bugs prioritarios. ¿Se sabe en qué estado está?

Comment: Lo recordé al pasarle este mensaje. A ver si comenta algo tambien al respecto

Comment: @Juan M el bug parece que ha vuelto: actualicé la pregunta con el ejemplo.

Comment: Ok, reportaré esto ahora.

Comment: Esto se ha corregido de nuevo.

Comment: @JuanM sigue sin estar corregido. Volví a actualizar

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' etiqueta de revision añadida, ya veo que sigue fallando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

When generating the hot meta questions sidebar on non-English sites, we will now fetch the list of synonyms starting with `status-` and exclude posts with the target tag.

Comment: Thanks. It was reported in Meta.SE as well: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328536/