# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre etiquetas [react] y [reactjs]? ¿No deberían ser sinónimas?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas

He visto que existen creadas ambas etiquetas [react](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react) y  [reactjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs).
Ambas tienen exactamente la misma descripción y muchas de las preguntas tienen ambas etiquetas o algunas una u otra, lo cual creo no contribuye en algo, más bien dificulta la tarea para quienes nos interesamos en seguir las preguntas de dicha librería.

¿No debería una ser sinónimo de la otra? O quizás combinarlas en una sola.

Comment: Creo que es una buena idea. Si nadie viene con un argumento en contra, las combinaré. ¿Cuál debería ser la principal: react o reactjs?

Comment: Parece lógico. En SO son sinónimas, siendo reactjs la principal: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/reactjs/synonyms

Comment: Lo mismo hice con [tag:vue] y [tag:vuejs]. En ese caso, elimine todas las que decian vue ya que no eran tantas...

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro hacelo tambien para las de vue.. asi evito ir limpiando una vez por semana... vue.js seria la principal...

Comment: @gbianchi combiné también [tag:vue] y [tag:vue.js]. ¿Habías hecho una petición anteriormente? (para marcarla como cerrada).

Comment: nop.. pero ya que estabamos.. genial @AlvaroMontoro.. cha gracias...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Se creó un sinónimo y procedió a la combinación de ambas etiquetas:

- [react](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react) → [reactjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs)

Como consecuencia del cambio, se sustituyó la etiqueta [react](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react) por [reactjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) en 172 preguntas.

---

Como sugerencia en los comentarios, también se creó un sinónimo de [vue](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue) a [vue.js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js). Como no había ninguna pregunta restante con la etiqueta [vue](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue), ninguna publicación se vio afectada por el cambio.