# ¿Podríamos hacer la etiqueta [management-studio] un sinónimo de ssms?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

La etiqueta [management-studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/management-studio) tiene 10 preguntas, todas relacionadas con SSMS.

La etiqueta [ssms](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssms) tiene 18 preguntas y tiene algo en la wiki. Además, el nombre completo de la herramienta es ese, SSMS.

¿Podríamos hacer que la primera sea sinónimo de la segunda?

Comment: Sin duda. De hecho [tag:management-studio] no tiene ni siquiera orientacion de uso. Por mi adelante

Comment: Ya dejé sugerida una versión mejorada de la información de la etiqueta [ssms]. Ya vi que está sugerido el sinónimo pero no tengo reputación suficiente en la etiqueta para votar a favor :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ya está realizado. Ahora [management-studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/management-studio) es sinónimo de [ssms](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssms).