# Quemar etiqueta [multiple]

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado, solicitud-de-lista-negra

Actualmente hay unas 15 preguntas etiquetadas [multiple](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple).

Las preguntas van desde relacionadas a combos y grillas con opción de selección múltiple y herencia múltiple, hasta realizar consultas SQL sobre multiples tablas.

Sobra decir que no hay un wiki de etiqueta que oriente sobre su uso y que, en mi opinión, la etiqueta no hace ningún sentido.

Creo también que debiera ponerse en lista negra para evitar que re-aparezca.

### Edición

De acuerdo al comentario de @gbianchi, procederé a eliminar la etiqueta de las preguntas al llegar la propuesta a 8 votos positivos, o una diferencia de +10 en caso de llegar a tener votos negativos (actualmente no tiene ninguno).

Comment: no es necesario meterla en la lista negra.. si hay solo 15, alcanza con borrarlas de todas esas preguntas y solita va a desaparecer...

Comment: @gbianchi, ahora vi por allí la etiqueta [rutas-dinamicas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rutas-dinamicas), ¿debiera lanzar otra pregunta para quemarla o confiar en mi criterio y simplemente eliminar la etiqueta de las preguntas?

Comment: @jachguate existe [tag:rutas], lo mismo se puede sustituir por esa.

Comment: No entiendo. ¿Que tiene de malo tener la etiqueta multiple?

Comment: Es una especie de meta-etiqueta, según se describe en el artículo sobre [etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) en el centro de ayuda. Como se evidencia en mi propuesta, la etiqueta está siendo utilizada como _bolsón_ para muchas cosas distintas y no relacionadas, y esa no es la idea sobre la que se utiliza una etiqueta. Por la misma razón, la wiki de la etiqueta está vacía y definitivamente no veo a nadie diciendo: Yo soy/quiero ser experto en [multiple] y que de seguimiento a la etiqueta para responder a las preguntas que aparezcan.

Comment: @fedorqui, EMHO, [rutas] es una meta-etiqueta y también debiera quemarse. ¿Has visto la variedad de preguntas que hay en ella? Rutas de archivos del sistema operativo, rutas de google maps, rutas en un servidor web/api, etc. Y la wiki de etiqueta, vacía, no hay manera de decir cuales preguntas si pertenecen y cuales no... además, ¿quién es experto en rutas?

Comment: Mmm, cierto. Lo mismo podría reconducirse a algo concreto, pero te doy la razón en que es algo tan amplio que ahora mismo no significa nada.

Comment: @gbianchi si le ponéis [meta-tag:estado-completado] supongo que dejaría de salir en el menú lateral ([o no](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3495/83)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Al haber alcanzado +10 y siguiendo la recomendación de @gbianchi, he realizado la *tarea de limpieza*, borrándola de las etiquetas de las distintas preguntas que la tenían, con lo cual se quemará de manera automática.

Comment: aún aparece en unas cuantas preguntas: [tag:multiple]

Comment: Gracias por hacermelo ver... veía un efecto _extraño_ al buscar por la etiqueta, porque aparecían por un instante algunas preguntas y luego todo quedaba en blanco, supuse que era por el funcionamiento del caché y que con el tiempo, pero ahora que lo comentaste lo vi con más detenimiento y era por mi configuración de etiquetas ignoradas. Tuve que quitar algunas de mis preferencias para lograr ver las preguntas y diría que ahora si ya terminé de editarlas. Gracias por el comentario.

Comment: ¡Gracias a ti por el trabajo!